# CustomPermissionEvaluator is not getting invoked in Spring 3.1

Tags: spring-security

I have implemented a Custom PermissionEvaluator and configured it as follows

```
<security:http access-denied-page="/" auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:anonymous />
    <security:form-login always-use-default-target="false" default-target-url="/people/login/redirect" login-page="/people/login" login-processing-url="/people/login/submit" password-parameter="password" username-parameter="emailAddress" />
    <security:logout delete-cookies="true" invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/people/login/redirect" logout-url="/people/logout" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager erase-credentials="false">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:global-method-security jsr250-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" >
    <security:expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
</security:global-method-security>


<bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
     <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="appPermissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>

<bean class="com.web.security.ApplicationPermissionEvaluator" id="appPermissionEvaluator" />
```

Then I applied hasPermissionCheck on one method on one of my ControllerClass as follows

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#accountCode, 'AdministerPosition')")
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value =  "/cloud/{account}/position")
    public String list(@PathVariable String account, @RequestParam(required = false, value = URLParameter.ACCOUNT_CODE) final String accountCode, final Model model) {

}
```

Here in this case I never get a control in my `ApplicationPermissionEvaluator` class.

I found that always `DenyAllPermissionEvaluator` gets executed in my case with following error message

```
DenyAllPermissionEvaluator - Denying user ****** permission 'AdministerPosition'
```

Please advice me on this asap. I am really stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

The way to get this working is to configure `<security:global-method-security ..>` in your spring mvc context, not the main context

i.e. in here `mvc-servlet-context.xml`

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/mvc-servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```